# Triple crank, extra click while downshifting

Tags: shimano, shifter, derailleur-front, brifters

I have an Ultegra triple crankset and shifters on a Giant road bike. When downshifting from the outer ring to the middle ring it requires an extra click.

I've experienced this on several triple chainring bikes that I've owned and wondered if it is just the nature of a triple or if I'm out of adjustment somewhere?

Comment: Some shifters have an extra click that is used to 'trim' the front derailleur as the chain moves across the cassette.  It could possibly be that.

Comment: Could be that. It seem like another full click. It’s odd also that it’s not there when shifting outward from inner ring to big ring it’s three clicks (really not clicks I guess on front) then on the way back there is an extra shift to go from outer to middle. Thank Andy

Comment: A newer double has (may have) 4 clicks a triple as many as six positions for trimming purposes as @AndyP writes. The FD has a position for the large sprockets and another for the small sprockets of the cassette, this possibly for each ring on the crank but at least for the middle-most.

Comment: Pre-existing questions, that are around the same subject without being exact dupes  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/55993/one-extra-position-on-front-derailleur-besides-trim  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/how-do-i-use-the-trim-function-correctly-on-shimano-shifters  and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/my-left-sti-shifter-has-5-positions-for-a-double-crankset

Answer (score 2):

Some shifters have an extra click that is used to 'trim' the front derailleur as the chain moves across the cassette.  This is to eliminate the noise of the chain gently rubbing the plates of the FD.

This data sheet for an Ultegra 6700 shifter has a section to explain this feature:
https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/si/SI-6SC0A-002-ENG.pdf